# Show users an error message whenever they select wrong input in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular-material2, angular2-formbuilder

I am building a component (html, css, spec.ts, ts) in angular in which I always want `endDate > startDate` so I have added validator to do this check. Below is my HTML form for that:

```html
<form class="unavailability-form" [formGroup]="unavailabilityForm" *ngIf="loaded">
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="container"  fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="start-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="end-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="2">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="endDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="unavailability-reason" >
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="{{'PORTAL.UNAVAILABILITYREASON' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="unavailabilityReason" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.unavailabilityReason" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
      <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="100%">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!unavailabilityForm.valid || !componentPermission.writePermission" (click)="onSave()">{{'PORTAL.CONFIRM' | translate}}</button>
        <!--<button mat-raised-button [matDialogClose]="canceled" color="primary">{{'PORTAL.CANCEL' | translate}}</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

And below is my angular code and I have also added the validators as well as shown below. I want to show users an error message whenever they select `endDate` less than `startDate`. How can I do that in angular with my code? I am not able to figure this out.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.getParams();
    this.getPermissions();
    this.validateForm();
}

validateForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': ['', Validators.required],
      'endDate': ['', Validators.required],
      'unavailabilityReason': ['']
    }, { validator: this.dateLessThan('startDate', 'endDate') });
  }

  dateLessThan(from: string, to: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
      let f = group.controls[from];
      let t = group.controls[to];
      if (f.value > t.value) {
        return {
          dates: "Date from should be less than Date to"
        };
      }
      return {};
    }
  }
```

Comment: One way could be that on ngModelChange, call a function that will check the start date and end date and then display the error.

Comment: @tumulr I think m already checking for an error right with my own validator? I do have my own validator that checks the error but confusion is how can I show the error to the user?

Answer (score 0):

in your component's HTML template, preset the message inside a div:

```html
<div [hidden]="dates_valid" class="invalid_date">
  Date from should be less than Date to
</div>
```

manage `dates_valid` boolean to hide or show it in the component.